# Xamarin.Auth change the "Authenticate" title

Tags: authentication, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Anyone knows if i can localize or just change the title "Authenticate" when Xamarin.Auth shows (facebook etc) login screens?

thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Okay, answering my own question after spending several hours, just to find out that OAuth2Authenticator class inherits from Authenticator class with a read/write property Title...

```
auth = new OAuth2Authenticator(
                        clientId: Constants.FacebookClientId,  
                        scope: "email",
                        authorizeUrl: new Uri("https://www.facebook.com/v2.9/dialog/oauth"), // These values do not need changing
                        redirectUrl: new Uri("http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html")// These values do not need changing
                    );
auth.AllowCancel = true; //back button allowed 
auth.Title = "Facebook"; //pfffff :)
```